# Click on a element with specific text

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

Alright, I have a item which has this class `class="country"` and there are 12 elements with the same class. Now I want to get a element on its value. For example Italy. And now I want to click on a link in this item. The class of the link is `class="link"`. So basically I want to click the link of the item with the name Italy

My code at the moment:

```
cy.get('.country').should('have.text', 'Italy').click();
```

HTML

```
<div class="countries">
   <div class="text">
      <h3></h3> 
      <div class="country">Italy</div> 
      <h4>Yala</h4> 
      <p>test</p>
      <a class="link" href="/mysite">Show details</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should() is an assertion and won't select the element you want.
you probably want the contains() function.

```
cy.get('.country').contains('Italy').click()
```

Best

Comment: Actually correct but I wrote it pretty unclear so please watch my edited question

Comment: Can't you just chain the commands?
"cy.get('.country').contains('Italy').find(".link").click()" ?

Comment: Your link has to be *in* the <div> of the .country to work

Comment: Instead of using country just use the <h4> with the city